# How to create loop within a JSON request object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, easypost

I need to create multiple "items" to be used within a json request .

Here's a request that works:

```
customs_info = EasyPost::CustomsInfo.create(
        eel_pfc: 'NOEEI 30.37(a)',
        customs_certify: true,
        customs_signer: "first_name last_name",
        contents_type: 'merchandise',
        contents_explanation: '',
        restriction_type: 'none',
        restriction_comments: '',
        # non_delivery_option: 'abandon',
        customs_items: [
          {
          description: "asdf",
          quantity: 1,
          weight: 23,
          value: 23,
          # hs_tariff_number: '654321',
          origin_country: 'US'
          },
          {
          description: "1234568",
          quantity: 1,
          weight: 23,
          value: 23,
          # hs_tariff_number: '654321',
          origin_country: 'US'
          }
        ]
      )
```

What I need is to not need to manually set the `customs_items`.

I tried:

```
customs_info = EasyPost::CustomsInfo.create(
        eel_pfc: 'NOEEI 30.37(a)',
        customs_certify: true,
        customs_signer: "#{shipping_address.shipping_address_final.first_name} #{shipping_address.shipping_address_final.last_name}",
        contents_type: 'merchandise',
        contents_explanation: '',
        restriction_type: 'none',
        restriction_comments: '',
        # non_delivery_option: 'abandon',
        customs_items: [
        vendor_line_items.map do |li|
          {
          description: "#{li.shop_product.product.item.title}",
          quantity: li.quantity,
          weight: li.shop_product.product.weight,
          value: li.shop_product.price,
          # hs_tariff_number: '654321',
          origin_country: 'US'
          }
        end
        ]
      )
```

**Error Statement:** Parameters to create Custom Item(s) invalid or missing

How can I create the loop to work with the JSON request and work like the first example that works manually?

Comment: `map` already returns an array. Remove square brackets around it. `customs_items: vendor_line_items.map ...`.

Comment: Wow you the best

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `[]` that is surrounding the `vendor_line_itmes.map` code, you will be good to go.

```rb
customs_info = EasyPost::CustomsInfo.create(
    # ...
    customs_items: vendor_line_items.map do |li|
        {
            description: "#{li.shop_product.product.item.title}",
            quantity: li.quantity,
            # ...
        }
    end
    )
```

The map operation returns an array so the json you are currently generating would look like (note the array of arrays in customs_info):

```
{ 
    "eel_pfc": "NOEEI 30.37(a)",
    ...

    "customs_info": [
        [
            {
                "description": "...",
                "quantity": 5,
                ...
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```